# moderntimeline - same entry, two time spans

Tags: moderncv, cv, moderntimeline

I'm updating my CV using the [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) class with [moderntimeline](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline), and most of it is looking really nice by now.

However, one of my previous positions I held twice, with a year-long break in the middle. Currently I just have one item spanning from 2003 to 2007 and the one above it from 2005 to 2006. It would be real nice if I could typeset this as a "gap" in the timeline entry for this item, matching the rectangle representing what I did during the break.

*(If it's unclear what I mean, please let me know and I'll try to generate some images...)*

#### MWE:

Here's an example of what it looks like right now:

[image: MWE]

What I'd like, is a "gap" in the longer bar, matching the shorter bar above it, so that the timeline shows that I did one thing, then another, and then "jumped back" to the first one, rather than doing two things simultaneously for a while.

Code for the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\tlmaxdates{2005}{2015}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tlcventry{2010}{2011}{Position 2}{Another company}{Somewhere else}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}
\tlcventry{2007}{2013}{Position 1}{A Company}{Somewhere}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you include a minimal example document that can serve as a framework to work on a solution, ideally together with a mock-up picture of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Jake: Clearer? I don't know how to generate a mockup that shows what I want in a good way, so I hope my explanations are sufficient.

Answer (score 14):

If I understood you correctly, the code below does what you want: the newly defined `\gaptlcventry` command acts in a similar fashion to `\tlcventry` but gives you a gap in the timeline; the new command has nine mandatory arguments (if you want to keep the first optional argument, as in `\tlcventry`, some more work will have to be done):

```
\gaptlcventry{1999}{2003}{2010}{2022}{WYSIWYG User}{Unnamed Company}
  {Somewhere}{}{Tried hard to typeset documents}
```

The above example will give a gap between 2003 and 2010. A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\tlmaxdates{2005}{2015}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gaptlcventry}[9]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{ifthenelse(#4==0,\tl@lastyear,#4)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#1-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(#2-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startsfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%new
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endsfraction{(#4-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%new
%
\pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{#4}%
\ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt 
  \def\tl@startlabel{\tl@since #1} 
  \def\tl@startslabel{\tl@since #3}%new 
\else 
  \def\tl@startlabel{#1} 
  \def\tl@startslabel{#3}%new 
\fi
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
    \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
    \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
       rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
    \fill [color1] (0,0)
       ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
       node [tl@startyear] {\tl@startlabel}
       rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt)
       node [tl@endyear] {\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#2==0,,#2)}\pgfmathresult}
       (\hintscolumnwidth,0pt) ;
%%new
    \fill [color1] (0,0)
       ++(\tl@startsfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
       node [tl@startyear] {\tl@startslabel}
       rectangle (\tl@endsfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt)
       node [tl@endyear] {\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#4==0,,#4)}\pgfmathresult}
       (\hintscolumnwidth,0pt) ;
%%endnew
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{#4} 
    \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt
       \shade [left color=color1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
           rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
%%new
       \shade [left color=color1] (\tl@startsfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
           rectangle (\tl@endsfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
%%endnew
    \else
       \fill [color1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
           rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
%%new
       \fill [color1] (\tl@startsfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
           rectangle (\tl@endsfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
%%endnew
    \fi
    }%
}%
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tlcventry{2010}{2011}{Position 2}{Another company}{Somewhere else}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}
\gaptlcventry{2007}{2010}{2011}{2013}{Position 1}{A Company}{Somewhere}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}

\tlcventry{2008}{2013}{Position 3}{Another company}{Somewhere else}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}
\gaptlcventry{2006}{2008}{2013}{2014}{Position 4}{A Company}{Somewhere}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@GonzaloMedina's excellent answer helped me while designing my own CV using `moderntimeline`. However, while it still works fine, the package has had some updates in the meantime, especially a nice mechanism for taking not only the year but also the month into account for the calculation of the timeline bars. Since this functionality is missing in the answer already given I adapted it to a) use the current `moderntimeline` functionality for processing dates and b) accept an arbitrary number of time periods (even though more than two will usually get in each other's way due to too little space). I thought this might be useful if someone else is looking for this kind of "gapped" CV entry which is why I wrote this answer.

The interface for my version of `\gaptlcventry` is a bit different from the one @GonzaloMedina provided: Mine takes 8 arguments, the first of which is the optional color choice which is also present in `moderntimeline`'s original commands. The second and third arguments take lists of the start and end years for the time periods, respectively, e.g. two periods 2009-2010 and 2013-2015 would be given as `{2009, 2013}` for the second argument and `{2010, 2015}` for the third argument.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\tlmaxdates{2005}{2015}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gaptlcventry}[8][color1]{%
\cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
    \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
    \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
      rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
    \foreach \start [count=\c] in {#2}
    \foreach \end [count=\d] in {#3}
        {\ifnum\c=\d
            \tl@formatendyear{\end}
            \tl@formatstartyear{\start}
            \fill [fill=none, #1] (0,0)
              ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
              node [tl@startyear] {\tl@startlabel}
              rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt)
              node [tl@endyear] {\tl@endlabel}
              (\hintscolumnwidth,0pt) ;
            \ifissince
              \newdimen\fullcolorwidth
              \pgfmathsetlength\fullcolorwidth{\tl@startfraction*(1+(1-\tl@startfraction)*\tl@nsfrac)*\hintscolumnwidth}
              \fill [color=#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
                  rectangle (\fullcolorwidth,\tl@width);
              \shade [left color=#1] (\fullcolorwidth,0)
                  rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
            \else
              \fill [color=#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
                  rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
            \fi
        \fi
        }
    }%
}%
{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tlcventry{2010}{2011}{Position 2}{Another company}{Somewhere else}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}
\gaptlcventry{2006/1, 2011/5}{2009/4, 2013/1}{Position 1}{A Company}{Somewhere}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}

\tlcventry{2008}{2013}{Position 3}{Another company}{Somewhere else}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}
\gaptlcventry{2006, 2013}{2008, 2014}{Position 4}{A Company}{Somewhere}{}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam vestibulum tristique porta. Sed quis diam urna. Mauris blandit quam non leo pulvinar quis dapibus diam consectetur. Sed interdum facilisis tellus.}

\end{document}
```

[image]